# Can't boot with secure boot and with the kernel signed

Tags: kernel, uefi, grub-efi, secure-boot, signature

I want to use Secure Boot with my own keys and with the kernels that I sign. I have gotten Grub to boot, but not with the signed kernel. I get this: "Error: /vmlinuz-5.4.0.91-generic has invalid signature" message.

This is what I have done:

```
mkdir keys
cd keys

efi-readvar -v dbx -o dbx.esl

# (reboot and clear default secureboot keys in the firmware config)

export myuuid=e9ffcff5-9186-4da1-ae89-654000af85eb

# create keys
openssl req -subj "/CN=SecBoot PK cert/"  -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 730 -outform PEM -keyout "PK.key"  -out "PK.pem"
openssl req -subj "/CN=SecBoot KEK cert/" -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 730 -outform PEM -keyout "KEK.key" -out "KEK.pem"
openssl req -subj "/CN=SecBoot db cert/"  -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 730 -outform PEM -keyout "db.key"  -out "db.pem"

cert-to-efi-sig-list -g "$myuuid" PK.pem  PK.esl
cert-to-efi-sig-list -g "$myuuid" KEK.pem KEK.esl
cert-to-efi-sig-list -g "$myuuid" db.pem  db.esl

#sign keys
sign-efi-sig-list -g "$myuuid" -c PK.pem  -k PK.key  PK  PK.esl  PK.auth
sign-efi-sig-list -g "$myuuid" -c PK.pem  -k PK.key  KEK KEK.esl KEK.auth
sign-efi-sig-list -g "$myuuid" -c KEK.pem -k KEK.key db  db.esl  db.auth
sign-efi-sig-list -g "$myuuid" -c KEK.pem -k KEK.key dbx dbx.esl dbx.auth

# add keys in firmware
efi-updatevar -k PK.key  -g "$myuuid" -f PK.auth  PK
efi-updatevar -k PK.key  -g "$myuuid" -f KEK.auth KEK
efi-updatevar -k KEK.key -g "$myuuid" -f db.auth  db
efi-updatevar -k KEK.key -g "$myuuid" -f dbx.auth dbx

# remove current signature (optional, i tried removing and not removing)
sbattach --remove /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
sbattach --remove /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
sbattach --remove /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0.91-generic

# sign binaries
sbsign --key db.key --cert db.pem --output /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
sbsign --key db.key --cert db.pem --output /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
sbsign --key db.key --cert db.pem --output /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0.91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0.91-generic
```

Note 1: If possible, I don't want to use mok, because it requires a reboot and I'm trying to install using an unattended script.

Note 2: I have tried using shim-signed and booting works, but it boots even though I don't sign the kernel, so I don't consider it safe as it boots with any kernel.

EDIT: I use Ubuntu 20.04.3

Answer (score 0):

Setting PK will change mode to *user mode*. You should add it last.

```
efi-updatevar -a -k PK.key  -g "$myuuid" -c KEK.crt KEK
efi-updatevar -a -k KEK.key -g "$myuuid" -c DB.crt db
efi-updatevar -f PK.auth PK
```